# Interpolation methods when working with data from multiple pandas DataFrames?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, interpolation

I have a DataFrame that has many columns and I want interpolate to get y-values using x, y points and my known x- values.  I know how to carry out the interpolation by selecting one column (of each DataFrame) of x, y points and x-values.  My goal is to have a DataFrame containing all of the interpolated y-values.  Generally, I can obtain the y-values one of two ways (that I know of):

Here is an example of how my DataFrames are formatted:

```
random.seed( 30 )

df_x_pts = pd.DataFrame({
"x_pts_1": np.random.uniform(low=1, high=200, size=(10,)),
"x_pts_2": np.random.uniform(low=1, high=500, size=(10,)),
"x_pts_3": np.random.uniform(low=1, high=750, size=(10,)),})

df_y_pts = pd.DataFrame({
"y_pts_1": np.random.uniform(low=1, high=200, size=(10,)),
"y_pts_2": np.random.uniform(low=1, high=500, size=(10,)),
"y_pts_3": np.random.uniform(low=1, high=750, size=(10,)),})
    
df_x_vals = pd.DataFrame({
"x_vals_1": np.random.uniform(low=1, high=200, size=(50,)),
"x_vals_2": np.random.uniform(low=1, high=500, size=(50,)),
"x_vals_3": np.random.uniform(low=1, high=750, size=(50,)),})
```

**1)**  I can calculate this for each column in each DataFrame using scipy:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

y = df_y_pts["y_pts_1"]
x = df_x_pts["x_pts_1"]
# Fit the interpolation on the original index and values
f = interp1d(x, y, kind='linear')

# Perform interpolation for values across the full desired index
f(x_val)
```

**2)** Or using numpy:

```
x_pts = df_x_pts["x_pts_1"]
y_pts = df_y_pts["y_pts_1"]
x_vals = df_x_vals["x_vals_1"]
y_vals = np.interp(x_vals, x_pts, y_pts)
print(y_vals)
```

What is a sensible method to accomplish this across the all DataFrames so that I return a single DataFrame that would look like df_x_vals, except a DataFrame that consists of all the interpolated y values?  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: why not DataFrame.interpolate?

Comment: is this the pandas interpolate method?  Most of the examples I have seen use it to interpolate the row values within the columns, which is not exactly what I am looking for in this example.

Comment: [`pd.DataFrame.interpolate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html)  You can use one of the following methods: 'linear', 'time', 'index', 'pad', 'nearest', 'krogh', or 'from_derivates'.

Comment: I have used this function to interpolate between missing values within a column; how do you use this to interpolate values between columns, instead of down the row?

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party and not enough rep for a comment, so I am formulating this as an answer:

> how do you use this to interpolate values between columns, instead of down the row?

Check the `axis` argument of [`DataFrame.Interpolate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html), I believe this is what you want.

Basically `...interpolate(..., axis=1)`